# Value of surface Integral

Tags: vector-analysis

Let S be the part of the surface $z = x^2+y^2$ which lies under the plane $z=4$.

What is the value of the surface integral $\iint_S z \, ds \, \,$?

**What I've done so far**:

I have used the surface integral formula however I do not know if I need to convert to polar coordinates for the boundaries when integrating? i can't seem to figure out the boundaries.

I have set up the interval as follows:

$\int \int (x^2+y^2) \sqrt{1+4(x^2+y^2)} \, dx \, dy$

Comment: Please edit your question showing how you have set up the integral. The bound is pretty straightforward given $0 \leq z \leq 4$ and $z = x^2 + y^2$.  Learn basic mathjax. It will help on this site.

Comment: I have added how I have set up the integral. thank you for editing the question to the correct coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\displaystyle \iint_S z \, dS = \iint (x^2+y^2) \sqrt{1+4(x^2+y^2)} \, \,dx \,dy \, \,$ is correct.

$x^2 + y^2 = r^2 = z \leq 4 \,$ so $ \,0 \leq r \leq 2$. Your integral becomes

$\displaystyle  =\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^2 r^2 \sqrt{1+4r^2} \, \, r \, dr \, d \theta = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^2 r^3 \sqrt{1+4r^2} \, dr \, d \theta$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I can take it from here thank you very much, although could you quickly explain where r cubed comes from?

Comment: In polar coordinates, double integral ($dA$) is given by $r \, dr \, d \theta$. You already have $r^2$ in the integrand from before. That makes it $r^3$.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I got a final answer of Pi/60(391sqrt(17)+1). can you confirm if this is correct? (sorry for not inputting the right code)

Comment: Yes that is correct. Pls learn basic mathjax. It is hard to read your math :)

Comment: Thank you sir! I will learn it especially for you x